# Switch case with dynamic array values

Tags: php, laravel

This is the array `["2","3","7","5"]` and the values will change and sometimes i shall get only four values, some time 7 and some times 10 so i may get maximum of 15 values in that array.

How to make a switch case, or loop through each values in array and execute different function in each of the execution.

For example from the above instance for "2" i will be doing some updates, and 3 for a different updates etc. So , what i am proposing is , the switch case should not be dependent on values, it should be dependent of length of values, which is max of 15

So should i write 15 switch cases ? or what should i do ? Please guide. No code as i am struck

Comment: I always avoid switch blocks if a lookup array will work.  Please show more context in your question.

Comment: The array `["2","3","7","5"]` is "id" of users, and the length of array may differ from 1 to 15 max, so i need to loop through all incoming arrays and execute a separate function for each values in array, 2 will have a different function and 3 will have another ! So , i need to loop 15 times as default and execute various function for each loop.

Comment: Please edit your question to reveal the relevant portions of your script.

Comment: Selecting the best design for your script will probably need to factor-in what the functions _actually_ do, whether their behavior can be logically/sensibly merged, and why you're using "magical integers" to begin with.  I generally steer away from `switch` block and I steer farther away from variable variables and variable function names.  The former makes bloated code, the latter negatively impacts code readability.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way, to make it easy would be using variable functions.
This is simple to use, and you can use it for any functions, 1..4..15..N, variable function will do all work.

```
foreach($array as $id) { 
    $myFunction = "function".$id;
    $myFunction();
}
```

You have to name your functions as "function{id}";

```
function function2(){
    //...
}
function function5(){
    //...
}
function functionN(){
    //...
}
```

Comment: whats the difference it gonna make if i use switch statement ?

Comment: With switch statement you will have a large code, repeted code, as all cases call a function.
If you want to add more function will be add more cases, with this simple solution, you dont have to worry about it.

Answer (score -1):

This is based on value, irrespective of array size.

```
foreach($array as $value){
 if($value==1){
    function_one();
  }
 else if($value==2){
    function_one();

  }
 else if($value==3){
    function_one();

  }
/// and so on

}
```

Comment: whats the difference it gonna make if i use switch statement ?

Comment: no difference, switch is just another way of dealing with conditions

Comment: will that make any difference in performance ? or time of execution ?

Comment: This is not great advice because a battery of if-elseif-else conditions will evaluate `$value` up to  _n_ times.  A switch block will evaluate `$value` just once.  This answer should not be implemented.

Comment: @mickmackusa I didn't get your point. It's if else if which will execute one statement at a time, it's not the set of all ifs which will always execute in all the cases.. This will exactly the same as switch (with break definitely). Share your thoughts. thanks.

Comment: If `$value = 15` then there will be 15 separate evaluations.  Switch doesn't suffer from performing so many evaluations, it evaluates once then executes the appropriate case -- this is basically the only thing that is good about switch blocks.